# How appropriate is "Are you kidding me" in a speech in class?

Tags: word-usage, politeness

Can I say

> Are you kidding me?

in a speech in class or is there a politer way of saying this?

**EDIT:** Is it okay to use this phrase if I want to express that I'm surprised of a poll?

Comment: I think context is everything. If you were in my serious class, I might say no, but perhaps I also think that humour is a good way to make a point, even in regards to a serious subject. I think we need more info to give a full answer.

Comment: It depends entirely on how polite the speech is supposed to be. "In a speech class" doesn't really provide enough information.

Comment: @J.R. I'm sorry about this. I've updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer that exactly without more context. It is informal, but contains no curse words or insults. I doubt an audience would take offense if it were used rhetorically, but like anything you need to be careful.

Acceptable:

> The UN sustainability report suggests that Sub Saharan Africa will run out of fresh water by 2021, leaving thousands to die of thirst. Are you kidding me? Can we really stand by and let this happen?

Unacceptable:

Your boss comes up and tells you that in order to make the big deadline everyone will have to work late tonight, and you respond with

> Are you kidding me?

If you're in a language class it depends on the teacher. It's not rude, but its not "eloquent" either.

Comment: I'd upvote this but you failed to give any more "polite" (or at least "politic") options.

Answer (score 2):

It's very hard to give a general answer just from that information. "Are you kidding me" is quite an informal idiom, but depending on the nature and overall tone of your speech it could be anywhere from perfectly appropriate to completely inappropriate.

There are many more formal ways to express incredulity - such as "I find it hard to believe" or "It is unfathomable that..."

Comment: "Are you kidding me?" can also be an effective expression to use in a speech with some humorous elements.

Answer (score 1):

"Arguably, what does something have to do with *whatever the subject is*."

"I have trouble believing, *this information*, because..."

“I see what you’re saying/ why people think this, but…”

"I disagree with that point because..."

If your subject is controversial, like a religion class, err on the side of caution. Do not even remotely ask if the person is kidding or joking. Just politely say, " I think this (your argument) is true because..."

If you don't think they are kidding and you want to politely disagree, "I'm sorry but I disagree." Then explain why.

If you are being asked to  add work/another paper to your workload, "That is adding a lot of work. Is this a priority for you?" Don't ask the boss if s/he is kidding you.

"The results of the poll surprised/shocked/took me by surprise because..." You could add, if you want smiles and perhaps a laugh, "I mean are you kidding me? I can hardly believe that person was elected in spite of all we know about him!"